# How to show all XSL elements?

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4, xslt, apache-fop

The XML file contains Accounts and a list of Account (contains ID and AccountDescription).
In the below example, there are 2 Account.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Accounts>
 <Account>
  <ID>5</ID>
  <AccountDescription>Account Description 5</AccountDescription>
 </Account>
 <Account>
  <ID>8</ID>
  <AccountDescription>Account Description 8</AccountDescription>
  </Account>
</Accounts>
```

When using the below XSL, it creates a PDF file with 2 pages, and each page has the header ID and AccountDescription, but there is no data/content underneath it, like this:

On page 1:

> ID                 AccountDescription

On page 2:

> ID                 AccountDescription

I would like to show the data like this:

> ID      AccountDescription
>
> 5       Account Description 5
>
> 8       Account Description 8

How can I do that ? Thank you.

This is my current XSL:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="Accounts">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">  
  <fo:layout-master-set>
          <fo:simple-page-master 
              master-name="main"
              margin-top="0px"
              margin-bottom="0px"
              margin-left="18px"
              margin-right="18px">
              <fo:region-body margin-top="0.75in" margin-bottom="2in" margin-left="18px" margin-right="18px"/>
              <fo:region-before extent="0.75in"/>
              <fo:region-after extent="1.5in"/>
              <fo:region-end extent="75px"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Account"/>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Account">
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="main">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:table font-size="10pt">
            <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="55mm"/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell >
                        <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell >
                        <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="AccountDescription"/></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:flow>

</fo:page-sequence>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're trying to apply-templates to/match `AccountRow`, but that element doesn't exist in your sample XML. Is that an issue with your stylesheet or an issue with your sample?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I edited my original post, so now I am not calling <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountRow"/>. Instead, I do <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></fo:block>.
With this, I do see the data, but each data shows on different page, ie: Page 1 I have 5 - Account Description 5, and on Page 2 I have 8 - Account Description 8.  How can I show all data in the same page ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I show all data in the same page ?

You need to use only one `fo:page-sequence`. Move it from the `Account` template up into the `Accounts` template.

**Updated XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <xsl:template match="Accounts">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">  
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master 
          master-name="main"
          margin-top="0px"
          margin-bottom="0px"
          margin-left="18px"
          margin-right="18px">
          <fo:region-body margin-top="0.75in" margin-bottom="2in" margin-left="18px" margin-right="18px"/>
          <fo:region-before extent="0.75in"/>
          <fo:region-after extent="1.5in"/>
          <fo:region-end extent="75px"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Account"/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Account">
    <fo:table font-size="10pt">
      <fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/>
      <fo:table-column column-width="55mm"/>
      <fo:table-body>
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell >
            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="ID"/></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell >
            <fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="AccountDescription"/></fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works,Thanks! But,it repeats the column headers for each row.So, I made minor changes to it: <fo:page-sequence master-reference="main"><fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"><fo:table font-size="6pt"><fo:table-column column-width="15mm"/><fo:table-column column-width="55mm"/><fo:table-body><fo:table-row><fo:table-cell ><fo:block text-align="right">ID</fo:block></fo:table-cell><fo:table-cell >                 <fo:block text-align="right">Account Description</fo:block></fo:table-cell></fo:table-row><xsl:apply-templates select="Account"/></fo:table-body></fo:table></fo:flow></fo:page-sequence>